# Layout android not working

Tags: java, android, android-layout, checkbox

I wanted to put dynamically the checkboxes with the names that I retrieve from the API one below the other, but when I run the code the checkbox I see just one and the others are in the back of it

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
arr = json.getJSONArray("functionality");

for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    String name = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
    CheckBox check  = new CheckBox(rootView.getContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                    check.setLayoutParams(lparams);
                                    check.setText(name);
                                    container.addView(check);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Add code of your container, please (creating it in java or your xml-layout). Is it really a Linear Layout?

Answer (score 0):

change below line in your code:

```
  CheckBox check  = new CheckBox(rootView.getContext());
```

to

```
 CheckBox check  = new CheckBox(container.getContext());
```

Comment: It didn't change, the bug is the same